# How to make same webpage available for different devices with different screen resolution in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a webpage and do not know how to make it compatible with different screen resolution like for pc and mobile's at same time.

Is there any official method to do it?

Or should i just have to play around with figures for:
`Top: vh;` and `left: vw;` to make it work.

If there is any better alternative then please let me know. Working on all those figures is really difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Razu's solution is ideal if you like writing your own CSS.

There are also frameworks and libraries which do the calculations for you ([Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) and [CSS-grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) are some good examples).

The downside to using those is that you need a bit of knowledge of CSS to adapt those to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is the best one to build responsive web page and it is an open source.

https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score -1):

**You can do it by media queries in this formate**

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { write css here }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { write css here }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) { write css here }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) { write css here }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { write css here }
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can use media queries for different screens**. For example

```
For mobile screen you can use:
@media screen only(max-width:576px){ //Your css code//}
And For Medium screens:
@media screen only(max-width:768px){ //Your css code//}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the media query to show the same webpage in different resulotion of devices. Here is the media query that you can use:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}

/* iPhone 5 (portrait &amp; landscape)----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}

/* iPhone 5 (landscape)----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}

/* iPhone 5 (portrait)----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}
```

Also follow the below link to know more:
[Media query for standard devices.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)